# How to set value of text-angular using C# protractor?

Tags: c#, angularjs, textangular, protractor-net

I am using text-angular (https://github.com/textAngular/textAngular) in my application as a textbox for writing mails.

While writing tests through C# protractor, I am unable to update the value of textbox. Even though I am able to access the underlying TextArea element but it is read-only, unable to set value using Text, SendKeys() etc.

Below is the code being put in html file

```
<text-angular id="txtComposeMessage" name="txtComposeMessage" class="youoi-text-angular" ng-model="emailCtrl.model.composeEmailNote"
                                  ta-toolbar="[['bold', 'italics', 'underline', 'strikeThrough', 'ul', 'ol', 'redo', 'undo', 'clear', 'justifyLeft', 'justifyCenter', 'justifyRight', 'indent', 'outdent', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'p']]"></text-angular>
```

and here is the rendered output in browser.

```
<text-angular id="txtComposeMessage" name="txtComposeMessage" class="youoi-text-angular ng-untouched ng-valid ta-root focussed ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" ng-model="emailCtrl.model.composeEmailNote" ta-toolbar="[['bold', 'italics', 'underline', 'strikeThrough', 'ul', 'ol', 'redo', 'undo', 'clear', 'justifyLeft', 'justifyCenter', 'justifyRight', 'indent', 'outdent', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'p']]" aria-invalid="false" style="">
    <div text-angular-toolbar="" name="textAngularToolbar4465315052159009" ta-toolbar="[['bold', 'italics', 'underline', 'strikeThrough', 'ul', 'ol', 'redo', 'undo', 'clear', 'justifyLeft', 'justifyCenter', 'justifyRight', 'indent', 'outdent', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'p']]" class="ta-toolbar btn-toolbar focussed">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="bold" ta-button="ta-button" ng-disabled="isDisabled()" tabindex="-1" ng-click="executeAction()" ng-class="displayActiveToolClass(active)" title="Bold" unselectable="on">
                <i class="fa fa-bold"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="italics" ta-button="ta-button" ng-disabled="isDisabled()" tabindex="-1" ng-click="executeAction()" ng-class="displayActiveToolClass(active)" title="Italic" unselectable="on">
                <i class="fa fa-italic"></i></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="underline" ta-button="ta-button" ng-disabled="isDisabled()" tabindex="-1" ng-click="executeAction()" ng-class="displayActiveToolClass(active)" title="Underline" unselectable="on">
                <i class="fa fa-underline"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="strikeThrough" ta-button="ta-button" ng-disabled="isDisabled()" tabindex="-1" ng-click="executeAction()" ng-class="displayActiveToolClass(active)" title="Strikethrough" unselectable="on">
                <i class="fa fa-strikethrough"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="ul" ta-button="ta-button" ng-disabled="isDisabled()" tabindex="-1" ng-click="executeAction()" ng-class="displayActiveToolClass(active)" title="Unordered List" unselectable="on">
                <i class="fa fa-list-ul"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="ol" ta-button="ta-button" ng-disabled="isDisabled()" tabindex="-1" ng-click="executeAction()" ng-class="displayActiveToolClass(active)" title="Ordered List" unselectable="on">
                <i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="redo" ta-button="ta-button" ng-disabled="isDisabled()" tabindex="-1" ng-click="executeAction()" ng-class="displayActiveToolClass(active)" title="Redo" unselectable="on">
                <i class="fa fa-repeat"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="undo" ta-button="ta-button" ng-disabled="isDisabled()" tabindex="-1" ng-click="executeAction()" ng-class="displayActiveToolClass(active)" title="Undo" unselectable="on">
                <i class="fa fa-undo"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="clear" ta-button="ta-button" ng-disabled="isDisabled()" tabindex="-1" ng-click="executeAction()" ng-class="displayActiveToolClass(active)" title="Clear formatting" unselectable="on">
                <i class="fa fa-ban"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active" name="justifyLeft" ta-button="ta-button" ng-disabled="isDisabled()" tabindex="-1" ng-click="executeAction()" ng-class="displayActiveToolClass(active)" title="Align text left" unselectable="on" style="">
                <i class="fa fa-align-left"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="justifyCenter" ta-button="ta-button" ng-disabled="isDisabled()" tabindex="-1" ng-click="executeAction()" ng-class="displayActiveToolClass(active)" title="Center" unselectable="on">
                <i class="fa fa-align-center"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="justifyRight" ta-button="ta-button" ng-disabled="isDisabled()" tabindex="-1" ng-click="executeAction()" ng-class="displayActiveToolClass(active)" title="Align text right" unselectable="on">
                <i class="fa fa-align-right"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="indent" ta-button="ta-button" ng-disabled="isDisabled()" tabindex="-1" ng-click="executeAction()" ng-class="displayActiveToolClass(active)" title="Increase indent" unselectable="on">
                <i class="fa fa-indent"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="outdent" ta-button="ta-button" ng-disabled="isDisabled()" tabindex="-1" ng-click="executeAction()" ng-class="displayActiveToolClass(active)" title="Decrease indent" unselectable="on">
                <i class="fa fa-outdent"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="h1" ta-button="ta-button" ng-disabled="isDisabled()" tabindex="-1" ng-click="executeAction()" ng-class="displayActiveToolClass(active)" title="Heading 1" unselectable="on">
                H1
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="h2" ta-button="ta-button" ng-disabled="isDisabled()" tabindex="-1" ng-click="executeAction()" ng-class="displayActiveToolClass(active)" title="Heading 2" unselectable="on">
                H2
            </button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="h3" ta-button="ta-button" ng-disabled="isDisabled()" tabindex="-1" ng-click="executeAction()" ng-class="displayActiveToolClass(active)" title="Heading 3" unselectable="on">
                H3
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="h4" ta-button="ta-button" ng-disabled="isDisabled()" tabindex="-1" ng-click="executeAction()" ng-class="displayActiveToolClass(active)" title="Heading 4" unselectable="on">
                H4
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="h5" ta-button="ta-button" ng-disabled="isDisabled()" tabindex="-1" ng-click="executeAction()" ng-class="displayActiveToolClass(active)" title="Heading 5" unselectable="on">
                H5
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="h6" ta-button="ta-button" ng-disabled="isDisabled()" tabindex="-1" ng-click="executeAction()" ng-class="displayActiveToolClass(active)" title="Heading 6" unselectable="on">
                H6
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active" name="p" ta-button="ta-button" ng-disabled="isDisabled()" tabindex="-1" ng-click="executeAction()" ng-class="displayActiveToolClass(active)" title="Paragraph" unselectable="on">
                P
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ta-scroll-window ta-text ta-editor form-control" ng-hide="showHtml" aria-hidden="false">
        <div class="popover fade bottom" style="max-width: none; width: 305px;">
            <div class="arrow"></div>
            <div class="popover-content"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ta-resizer-handle-overlay">
            <div class="ta-resizer-handle-background"></div>
            <div class="ta-resizer-handle-corner ta-resizer-handle-corner-tl"></div>
            <div class="ta-resizer-handle-corner ta-resizer-handle-corner-tr"></div>
            <div class="ta-resizer-handle-corner ta-resizer-handle-corner-bl"></div>
            <div class="ta-resizer-handle-corner ta-resizer-handle-corner-br"></div>
            <div class="ta-resizer-handle-info"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="taTextElement4465315052159009" contenteditable="true" ta-bind="ta-bind" ng-model="html" class="ng-valid ta-bind ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" aria-invalid="false" style="">
            <p>abcd</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <textarea id="taHtmlElement4465315052159009" ng-show="showHtml" ta-bind="ta-bind" ng-model="html" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ta-bind ta-html ta-editor form-control ng-hide ng-not-empty" aria-hidden="true" aria-invalid="false">
    </textarea>
    <input type="hidden" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;" name="txtComposeMessage" value="<p>abcd</p>">
</text-angular>
```

I am using below code to update value in textarea.

```
var txtMessage = _accessor.GetElement("txtComposeMessage").FindElement(By.XPath(@".//textarea"));
txtMessage.SendKeys("test message");
```

Getting below exception while trying to update it.

```
An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Comment: It seems you're selecting a text box which currently is not displayed in the UI. Are you sure you're selecting the right text box?

Comment: Yes Dejan, I'm selecting for right text box but that's not accessible some how.

Comment: The error message you get is raised when an element is not visible at the time of accessing it. Are you absolutely sure you're accessing the right element and that it's visible? Are you selecting it by ID? Is it maybe a timing issue? Try to sleep a second before accessing it.

Comment: Yes, I am accessing the right element and it has nothing to do with timing issue.
I have expanded the rendered output in my question, for your reference. Somehow main text area "taHtmlElement4465315052159009" is not editable.

Comment: `taHtmlElement4465315052159009` has a `ng-show` and a `ng-hide` directive which might hide the element (or prevent it from even showing) at the time of accessing it.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. Not sure how to update value in it. Will spend some more time on it.